# Group lines of a text file in files per category - Most efficient way

Tags: python, text-files

I have a huge text file (enough to fill my computer's memory) that I need to separate in smaller files.

The file contains CSV lines, where the first line is an ID:

```
ID1, val11, val12, val13
ID2, val21, val22, val23
ID1, val31, val32, val33
ID3, val41, val42, val43
```

I want to read each line, or groups of lines from the source file and create smaller files grouping the lines per ID:

```
File1:
    val11, val12, val13
    val31, val32, val33
File2:
    val21, val22, val23
File3:
    val41, val42, val43
```

So far I can do it with the following code, but that is taking reeeeally long (I don't have 10 days to do this).

```
def groupIDs(fileName,folder):
    loadedFile = open(fileName, 'r')
    firstLine = loadedFile.readline() #skip titles

    folder += "/"

    count = 0;

    for line in loadedFile:

        elems = line.split(',')
        id = elems[0]

        rest = ""
        for elem in elems[1:]:
            rest+=elem + ","

        with open(folder+id,'a') as f:
            f.write(rest[:-1])

        #printing progress
        count+=1
        if count % 50000 == 0:
            print(count)

    loadedFile.close()
```

The bottleneck seems to be HD performance, as shown by resource monitor (CPU usage is below 20%, memory is barely touched)

How can I improve this for best performance?

Comment: try to not close the files after writing each line, i.e. manually manage the open files, and only close all files when you have processed all the lines.

Comment: Won't this leave the files in memory? (I don't have enough memory)

Comment: opening and closing a file on each line may be the bottleneck

Comment: I was a good idea, but I almost immediately got `[Errno 24] Too many open files: 'someFileName'`.

Comment: then the code gets more complicated, because you have to limit the maximum number of open files (i.e. skip opening a file when you are at the limit), and do the remaining files in another pass. so you would need multiple passes to complete your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep it in ram and only flush out every few 1000 lines or when the ram is filled to a degree selectable by you.

You should also use context managers with files and use the `os.path` or `pathlib` modules from the std lib instead of manually using strings as pathes.

Here is a solution that saves every 10000 lines, adjust as fits your problem:

```
import os
from glob import iglob
from collections import defaultdict


def split_files_into_categories(inputfiles, outputdir):
    count = 0
    categories = defaultdict(bytearray)

    for inputfile in inputfiles:
        with open(inputfile, 'rb')  as f:
            next(f) # skip first line

            for line in f:

                if count % 10000 == 0:
                    save_results(categories, outputdir)
                    categories.clear()

                category, _, rest = line.partition(b',')

                categories[category] += rest
                count += 1

    save_results(categories, outputdir)


def save_results(categories, outputdir):
    for category, data in categories.items():
        with open(os.path.join(outputdir, category.decode() + '.csv'), 'ab') as f:
            f.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run on all csvs in the data folder
    split_files_into_categories(iglob('data/*.csv'), 'by_category')
```

A few explanations:

- I open the files in binary mode and use a `bytearray`, this prevents copying the data. In python strings are immutable, so `+=` creates a new string and reassigns it.
- `defaultdict(bytearray)` will create an empty `bytearray` for every new category, as soon as it is accessed for the first time.
- You could replace the `if count % 100000 == 0` with checking memory consumption like this:

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
  ```

  and then check

  ```
  # save results if process uses more than 1GB of ram
  if process.memory_info().rss > 1e9:
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do something similar, and as a contribution, I believe (not sure) that doing `line[len(category)+1:]` would be faster than `",".join(...)`, right?

Comment: Even better should be: `category, _, rest = line.partition(b',')`, i edited my answer.